# Display HTML page stored in SharePoint documents folder

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm working on a SharePoint web part that displays a number of different reports in different divs on the page.  In one of these divs, I need to display the HTML from a page we have stored in the 'Documents' container within SharePoint.  The info in the HTML page is retrieved from several different parts of the application, and is displayed differently, so basically we're using it as the source data.  I'm trying to figure out how to access the page from within the app and hopefully store the link to the file as a configurable setting so I can set it up for our dev/test/prod environments.

I've loaded the HTML file into the 'Documents' folder, and if I browse to it manually it displays fine but if I use the following:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
{
    using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
    }
}
```

I get a 403 error and in the response header the message, "Before opening files from this location you must first browse to the website and select the option to login automatically".

I thought the RunWithElevatedPriveleges would pass the credentials through but I'm pretty new to SharePoint.  Not sure if I'm using the right approach, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  There were a number of permissions problems but once those were sorted this code worked:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
      SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder("MainFolder/Lists/MainFolderDocs");

      if (folder.Exists)
      {
         SPFile file = web.GetFile("/MainFolder/Lists/MainFolderDocs/Mainlist.html");
         if (file.Exists)
         {
             using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file.OpenBinaryStream()))
                 {
                    string htmlCode = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    lChecklist.Text = htmlCode;
                 }
         }
       }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Put the pages into a standard document library, then use the page viewer web part.  The site asset library is used for other customization purposes.  You don't even need SharePoint Designer. Page viewer should be set as a "Web Page" because the web page viewer becomes essentially an IFRAME.

If still trouble... it may be a setting at the Web Application level thats causing issues with non-Microsoft files

Go to Central Admin > Manage Web Applications.  I then chose my Web Application and clicked on the "General Settings" button.  I then changed the Browser File Handling from "Strict" to "Permissive" and that fixed my issue.  I've included an attachment of the setting so you can read the text associated with it.

[image]

Comment: Hi Taj, thanks for the response.  I forgot that wrinkle, I'm already in a web part.  The users wanted a lot of custom reporting, so I just put a bunch of divs on the page and then displayed the corresponding report block inside of it, and then put all of that in a Web part